# AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

Tags: python, django

Я пытался сделать форму для создания поста, генерируя с помощью django widget-tweaks  поля для заполнения на bootstrap. Однако при запуске django выдал следующую ошибку:

> ```
>  AttributeError at /blog/post/create
>  'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'
> ```

Пишет что ошибка находится в views.py в строке

```py
 return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': 'form'})
```

Мой views.py:

```py
rom django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import View

from .models import Post, Tag
from .utils import  ObjectDetailMixin
from .forms import TagForm, PostForm
# Create your views here.
def posts_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})

class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
    model = Post
    template = 'blog/post_detail.html'
#   def get(self, request, slug):
        #post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug__iexact = slug)
        #return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context={'post': post})

class PostCreate(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': 'form'})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_post = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_post)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': 'bound_form'})


class TagDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
    model = Post
    template = 'blog/tag_detail.html'
    #def get(self, request, slug):
        #tag = Tag.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
        #return render(request, 'blog/tag_detail.html', context={'tag': tag})

class TagCreate (View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = TagForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/tag_create.html', context={'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        bound_form = TagForm(request.POST)
        if bound_form.is_valid():
            new_tag = bound_form.save()
            return redirect(new_tag)
        return render(request, 'blog/tag_create.html', context={'form': bound_form})

def tags_list(request):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})
```

.html файл страницы создания, которая создает ошибку:

```html
{% extends 'blog/base_blog.html'%}
{% block title %}
    Create Post - {{ blog.super }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    <form class="" action="{% url 'post_create_url'%}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% load widget_tweaks %}
        {% for field in form %}
         <div class="mb-5">{% render_field field class="form-control -lg" placeholder=field.label %}
             {% if field.errors %}
                 <div class="mb-5 alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">{{field.errors}}
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                 </div>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" >Create new tag</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Также по каким-то причинам он указывает в нулевую строчку файла base.html.
Сам base.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>
          {% block title %}
              Blog Engline
          {% endblock title %}
      </title>
  </head>
  <body style="background: gray">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Django.test</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'posts_list_url' %}">Blog<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/blog/post/create">Create Post</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " href="/blog/tags" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false">Tags</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 offset-md-2">
                {% block content%}
                There is no any content for you
                {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `context={'form': 'form'}`. Мне кажется, Вы не хотели передавать строку. Попробуйте так: `context={'form': form}`

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное , помогло. Можете написать как ответ, чтобы я мог повысить вам рейтинг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы опечатались, передав строку, вместо объекта формы.

*Исправленная версия:*

```py
return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': form})
```